# Is there a way to describe the situation of things being at 60° to one another?

Tags: phrase-requests

I came across the word 'trine' which was new to me and one of its meanings (in astronomy) is to describe the relative position of planets when they are in the aspect of 120° to one another (the sun being the centre of the circle).

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trine)

- 90° - 'at right angles'.
- 120° - 'in trine aspect'.
- 180° - 'diametrically opposite'.

But I cannot find a term for the 60° relationship.

Comment: Not that important, but  my answer was the first to suggest "sextile".

Comment: @NigelJ - anyway, a quick search would have given you the same result. Please do your own research before asking. here. Nothing personal!

Comment: My choice was based on what I saw when I used the appropriate links and my choice was based on my own aesthetic appreciation and my own personal opinion. A pleasant day to all contributors.

Comment: This is known as "facing each other" in Minnesotan.

Comment: I have raised the question of accepting answers on the Meta site in order to clarify what the rules are about this.

Comment: See - [Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11271/is-there-a-rule-that-the-first-correct-answer-must-be-accepted)

Comment: @user2922582 there's one minute difference between your post and that of Perry's, possibly less. IOW you posted the same(ish) answer. What the OP could have done was to wait a couple of hours before accepting an answer to see if other solutions turned up (doubtful in this scenario but you never know)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I didn’t mean to say that my answer was copied, or that OP should have accepted mine. But I have my reason to underline this issue. If anybody is feigning innocence, they are just feigning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - and yes, it is good practice to wait some time  before accepting  and OP probably should have waited a couple of hours for other possible suggestions, not two or three seconds, as they did.

Comment: @user2922582 Can you change your username to something more easily recognizable? It made sense to keep the numeric gibberish when you planned to only lightly interact on the site, but now that you’re a regular contributor again, the username is frustrating for the rest of we regulars. You can change it to “user999” or something if you still want to keep the “anonymity”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your word is [sextile](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sextile):

> An aspect of 60° (one sixth of a circle)
>
> ‘we find Jupiter in sextile to Neptune’

Answer (score 3):

There is a whole terminology in the astrology/astronomy area for the angular relations among celestial objects and interpreted meanings associated with each. This is called [Astrological aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_aspect) These angles are important for analyzing astrological charts which map out the angles among the sun, moon, and planets.

- **[conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(astronomy))** - when two bodies are at the same angular position or *zero degrees*. A solar eclipse, where the moon is in front of the sun, or any occultation is a conjunction. The new moon is in conjunction just not exactly (the moon is very very close, on the celestial sphere, to the sun then).
- **[sextile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextile)** - sixty degrees apart. Because 60 degrees is a sixth of the 360 in the full circle, and [(six is the root of 'sextile')](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=sextile)
- **square** or **quadrature** - ninety degrees apart. A half moon or first or third quarter is 'in square' with the sun.
- **trine** 120 degrees apart, because 120 is a third of 360 [(three is the root of 'trine')](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=trine).
- **[opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_(planets))** - 180 degrees apart. A full moon or a lunar eclipse is an opposition with the sun because the Earth is directly between the sun and moon.

The way to use all these aspects is to say 'X is **in (aspect) with** Y' for example:

> 'A moon in trine with the Sun is **[gibbous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waxing_Gibbous)**, but in sextile with the sun, it is crescent.'

Both opposition and conjunction are names for **[syzygy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygy_(astronomy))** which are three celestial bodies metaphorically '[yoked](https://www.etymonline.com/word/yoke)' together in a line, [sy - zygy](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=syzygy). See also [zeugma](https://www.etymonline.com/word/zeugma), [yoga](https://www.etymonline.com/word/yoga), and [join](https://www.etymonline.com/word/join), but not [yolk](https://www.etymonline.com/word/yolk).

There's a vocabulary for [*minor* angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_aspect#Minor_Aspects), but they are not as salient or important astrologically as the major aspects.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to terminology used also in [Horoscope](http://www.elbertwade.com/page152.html):

> - 360 divided by 1 = 360° (conjunction) - 360 divided by 2 = 180° (opposition) - 360 divided by 3 = 90° (square -- also called quadrate) -  360 divided by 4 = 120° (trine) - 360 divided by 5 = 72° (quintile) -  ***360 divided by 6 = 60° (sextile)***
> - ***When two planets are sextile***, they are in a highly compatible position. Sextiles are not extremely strong aspects, but they bring happy vibes, friendly interactions and general good cheer.